# Excel formula - If A=1 B=2.......Z=26. If you input CAT in cell it should display the result 24

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel formula - If A=1 B=2.......Z=26. If you input CAT in cell it should display the result 24 ie C+A+T. Not VB or JAVA or any programming language just the excel formula.

This is what I tried

```
=SUM(LOOKUP({"C","A","T"},B3:B28,C3:C28))
```

with input of below in the cells B3:B28,C3:C28. I want the result to display when I put in CAT in the cell.

```
A   1
B   2
C   3
D   4
E   5
F   6
G   7
H   8
I   9
J   10
K   11
L   12
M   13
N   14
O   15
P   16
Q   17
R   18
S   19
T   20
U   21
V   22
W   23
X   24
Y   25
Z   26
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: This is what I tried =SUM(LOOKUP({"C","A","T"},B3:B28,C3:C28)) with input of below in the cells B3:B28,C3:C28)  . I want the result to display when I put in CAT in the cell.                                                                                                    A 1
B 2
C 3
D 4
E 5
F 6
G 7
H 8
I 9
J 10
K 11
L 12
M 13
N 14
O 15
P 16
Q 17
R 18
S 19
T 20
U 21
V 22
W 23
X 24
Y 25
Z 26

Comment: Don't use the comment section to provide additional information to the question use the [edit] button instead. The information in the comments can be easily overlooked and formatted in a limited way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to iterate the letters and use CODE to return the value:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(CODE(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1))),1)))-64)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome. That worked. What if I give different values to the alphabets for example A=4 B= 8 randomly??? Is there a way that it reads the values that I input in cells and displays the answer?

Comment: That is different question.  This will not work for random numbers.

Comment: But `=SUMPRODUCT(LOOKUP(UPPER(MID(A1,ROW($XFD$1:INDEX($XFD:$XFD,LEN(A1))),1)),B3:B28,C3:C28))`